# Open Folder and Select multiple files

Tags: c#, file, explorer, directory

In C# I want to open explorer and in this explorer window must be selected some files. I do this like that:

```
        string fPath = newShabonFilePath;

        string arg = @"/select, ";

        int cnt = filePathes.Count;
        foreach (string s in filePathes)
        {
            if(cnt == 1)
                arg = arg + s;
            else
            {
                arg = arg + s + ",";
            }
            cnt--;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", arg);
```

But only the last file of "arg" is selected. How to make that all files of arg would be selected, when explorer window is opened..? I think its possible to do that, becouse I have seen many Windows app programs, which have this trick. In example, when I import pictures from my DSLR camera to the pc, finally apears windows explorer and all the new imported images are selected.

Maybe there is some option, to make all files to be selected from specified folder..?

Comment: What is your goal? If you want to select those files so that the user can easily copy them, why don't copy them yourself to the clipboard?

Comment: I only want to make these files visible, so that the user can see exactly only these new generated files.

Comment: can't just create a seperate folder of the new created files? And open that?

Answer (score 2):

`explorer.exe /select` only takes 1 argument. From [KB 314853](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853):

> /select,  Opens a window view with the specified folder, file, or program selected.

Answer (score 0):

Could you launch each file in the loop?

```
foreach (string s in filePaths)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, "+s);
```

P.S. [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) is a greatly underused feature of .NET